# firefox plugin that echoes out the html ids and class names

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome

What is the firefox or chrome plugin called that prints to the page the different html id's and class names?

Comment: This is not the plug-in shopping channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people use Firebug for developing sites in Firefox. It is similar to Chrome's Inspector. I believe this is what you are looking for. http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Yeah I have Firebug lite for Chrome. I remember a friend using something awhile back that would alter the page and displayed the html tags.